# Firebird SQL join recommendation

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird-3.0

I am using Firebird 3.0. I have 2 tables and I want to get the following result with one query, but I couldn't do this.

**USERS Table**

| ID | USER_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | User1 |
| 20 | User2 |
| 30 | User3 |
| 40 | User4 |
| 50 | User5 |

**CALL_HISTORY Table**

| ID | USER_ID | START_TIME | CALL_DIRECTION | STATUS | EXTEN | REMOTE_USER | DURATION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 09.02.2022 | I | 3 | 1007 | 00000000000 | 63 |
| 2 | 10 | 09.02.2022 | I | 3 | 1007 | 00000000000 | 37 |
| 3 | 10 | 09.02.2022 | I | 4 | 1007 | 00000000000 | 0 |
| 4 | 20 | 09.02.2022 | O | 3 | 1008 | 00000000000 | 33 |
| 5 | 20 | 09.02.2022 | O | 3 | 1008 | 00000000000 | 47 |
| 6 | 20 | 09.02.2022 | O | 3 | 1008 | 00000000000 | 10 |
| 7 | 30 | 09.02.2022 | O | 3 | 1028 | 00000000000 | 121 |
| 8 | 30 | 09.02.2022 | O | 3 | 1028 | 00000000000 | 37 |
| 9 | 30 | 09.02.2022 | O | 3 | 1028 | 00000000000 | 73 |
| 10 | 30 | 09.02.2022 | I | 3 | 1028 | 00000000000 | 61 |
| 11 | 40 | 09.02.2022 | I | 4 | 1013 | 00000000000 | 0 |

**Expected result**

| USER_NAME | NUM_INCOMING_CALL | DURATION_INCOMING_CALL | NUM_OUTGOING_CALL | DURATION_OUTGOING_CALL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User1 | 2 | 100 | null | null |
| User2 | null | null | 3 | 90 |
| User3 | 1 | 61 | 3 | 231 |

**Attempt**

Here is the query I tried (and there is also a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=e889195084224c459bdf09be2382568c)):

```
SELECT 
  outgoing_call.user_name,
  cast(incoming_call.num_incoming_call as bigint) as num_incoming_call,
  incoming_call.duration_incoming_call,
  cast(outgoing_call.num_outgoing_call as bigint) as num_outgoing_call,
  outgoing_call.duration_outgoing_call
from
  (select user_id, (select user_name from "USERS" where id=sch.user_id) user_name, count(id) num_outgoing_call, sum(duration) duration_outgoing_call
    from "CALL_HISTORY" sch
    where CALL_DIRECTION='O' AND (START_TIME BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-03-01') AND (STATUS=3) group by user_id
  ) as outgoing_call
full join
  (select user_id, (select user_name from "USERS" where id=sch.user_id) user_name, count(id) num_incoming_call, sum(duration) duration_incoming_call
    from "CALL_HISTORY" sch
    where CALL_DIRECTION='I' AND (START_TIME BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-03-01') AND (STATUS=3) group by user_id
  ) as incoming_call
on outgoing_call.user_name=incoming_call.user_name
```

The result set is not what I want. I also tried the query as "Right Join", "Left Join" and "Full Join" but, it didn't get the result I expected. Can a single query sentence be written to see the expected result?

Comment: Exactly what is the problem? And describe the logic that constructs your expected result. As an aside, please edit your title to summarize your actual problem.

Comment: I've been a little more descriptive. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is much simpler than you think. All you need is a simple join and conditional aggregates like `sum(case when call_direction='I' then duration end)`.

Look at this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=1d9cbe0e617f89d8bf698b1a22d4bd76

Comment: if such kind of quries is common one can offload the conditions into the computed field, so he can later easier reference them and had a one centralized point to edit the conditions if need be: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=3b34d773fe70a22f1c9bea70046d0439

Comment: Was it that simple? :)

Thanks @user1396427

Comment: Thanks for the info @Arioch 'The

Comment: With Firebird 4.0, you can also use the SQL standard [`FILTER` clause](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-aggfuncs): `sum() filter (where  call_direction='I')

Comment: wow, which SQL standard introduced FILTER ? yeah, syntactic sugar, but a handy one. @MarkRotteveel

Comment: @nakisen by definition aggregate functions only work on non-NULL values and just skip NULL ones. This has ot be remembered - you can use it for features like this - or you can inadvertently use it and then it becomes a bug rather hard to spot, if you do not know where to look into.

Comment: @Arioch'The It was introduced in SQL:2003.